# Usage of the word "interimly"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, is-it-a-word

I have a quick question: I used the word *interimly* talking to someone today. It went something like - 'I give you (someone) pat on the back for *interimely* filling someone's else shoes'. I am strongly inclined to think I used it incorrectly and there is no such word. I could have easily used *temporarily*.

Mind you, English is not my primary language.

How can I phrase it so that it's grammatically sound?

Comment: Hello, Teddy. Have you checked in any dictionaries to try to answer your question for yourself?

Comment: There is no such adverb. in an interim manner or way or in the interim.

Comment: @Lambie The normal adverbial expression is *ad interim*, and it's not English in origin despite its appearance in the OED.

Comment: Also, to avoid Latin: on an interim basis. He was appointed CEO **on an interim basis**.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in saying that you should have used the word temporarily, for example

> I'm giving you a pat on the back for temporarily filling someone's else shoes!

If you really want to use the word interim then re-phrase to something like

> I'm giving you a pat on the back for filling someone's else shoes in the interim!

As far as I'm aware 'interimely' isn't a valid word in the English language. It (and also 'interimly' which would be the expected spelling if it would become official) does not appear in any dictionary [1](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interim), [2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/interim), which is a good sign that it is 'not a word' (especially since 'interim' is a more educated non-slang term). There's always a chance that it could slip into 'wordedness' (not a word (also, not a word)) but it is fairly unginly sounding so I expect not.

Comment: Thanks a mil for your timeous response.

Comment: KilllingTime: I took the liberty of adding what it means to 'be a word' to your answer.

Comment: @Mitch That is far more of an edit than guidelines here would allow, which are normally only okay with correcting typos, providing a link to a resource, or reformatting something. Adding a large chunk of detail that was never provided in the first place is a major alteration to somebody else's work. (However well intended). I will leave it up to the author to keep, reject, or alter, but this should have really been provided as a suggestion in a comment instead.

Comment: The edit's ok with me. I was contemplating a similar edit myself.

Comment: I think it sounds incomplete to say "in the interim" without having defined the period in question one way or another, like, say, "Jerry will be back on Wednesday, but I'd like to thank you for filling his shoes in the interim." On the other hand it sounds okay to talk about an interim position without more details: "I'd like to give you a pat on the back for your work as interim police chief."

Answer (score 1):

"Interimly" as an adverb is a ***very*** rare usage; it's not something you'd use in general conversation or even most professional writing.

All of the [Google Books search results for "interimly"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22interimly%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) appear to be used within a legal context; where the lawyers are trying to be very precise about a specified interim period.

> EFFECTIVE DATE NOTE At 54 FR 1150 Jan 12 1989 §614.4320 was amended **interimly** by removing the words "and approved by the Farm Credit Administration" in the first sentence, effective Jan 6 1989. At 54 FR 50736 Dec 11 1989 the rule was adopted as final, effective upon the expiration of 30 days after publication, during which either or both Houses of Congress are in session Notice of effective date will be published in the FEDERAL REGISTER.

*Code of Federal Regulations: 1985-1999, Part 600 to End: Banking, US Government Printing Office, 1990*

Someone in the US Government reworded a regulation, and since Congress didn't object within a specified period, it became permanent.  Even here, this might not be the best choice of words. I might use "provisionally" instead.

Comment: OED attests *interim* as an adverb meaning "meanwhile", but normally it is found in adverbial expressions like *ad interim* or more rarely *per interim*.

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement to the previous answers.

I also checked the *Oxford English Dictionary (OED)* and *interimly* does not appear there (and neither does *interimely*).

None of the following dictionaries have it: [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interim), [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/interim) (formerly *Oxford*), [*American Heritage*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=interim), [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interim), [*vocabulary.com*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/interim), [*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/interim_1), [*Cambridge*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interim?q=interim_1), [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interim), [*Webster's New World College Dictionary, Fifth Ed.*](https://www.yourdictionary.com/interim) (via yourdictionary.com), [*Infoplease*](https://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/interim), [*dictionary.com*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interim), [*Webster's 1913 Dictionary*](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/interim), and [*freedictionary.org*](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=interim)

The following dictionaries list *interim* as an adverb, meaning *in the meantime, meanwhile* (as in, *Interim, take courage, and make your calculations anew*), with a note that it is rare or even archaic: the *OED*, [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/interim), [*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interim), [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interim), [*Infoplease*](https://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/interim), and [*dictionary.com*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/interim).

*Interimly* is also not present in [*Black's Law Dictionary, 8th ed.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000M4T9LA)

All these negative results notwithstanding, I think that it is pretty hard to argue against the results of the [searching of google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22interimly%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) that user Spencer quotes. Based on these results, I would say that *interimly* is rare, but certainly attested in legal literature.

**Idiomatic rephrasings**

As others have said, you can use *temporarily* or *in the interim* (where the latter assumes that the context makes it clear what intervening time the word *interim* refers to). See [the answer by user KillingTime](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/506353/155553). It is also possibel to use *ad interim* (*OED:* 'for an intervening or temporary period of time; in the meantime') and *per interim* (*OED:* 'for the meantime; during the intervening time. Now rare'), as tchrist mentioned. Sample usage (from *OED*):

> There should be, at least **ad interim,** a special military status for the territories.
>   There is nothing better than confessing our own soul **per interim.**

Thus in your case, it would be

*I'm giving you a pat on the back for filling someone's else shoes **ad interim**!*

Comment: No, not the highly dubious *?interimly*, but the adverbial [*ad interim*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2384) and [*per interim*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/237069) do both appear in the OED, and indeed [*interim* itself](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97823) has been known to be used adverbially.

Comment: @tchrist Ahh, paywalls, the bane of our existence.

Comment: temporarily take over a job; take over a position on an interim basis.